# What are the advantages to call a class as an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Suppose:
if I call one of my classes to my Main method, how many ways I can use the object ArrayList to make the list useful?

eg:

```
ArrayList <Account> listOfAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Can I use listOfAccounts as Integer? if yes, how? or how to covert listOfAccounts as Integer ArrayList so that I can use them as in the method below?
 class method:

```
int findMax(ArrayList <Integer> numberOfAccount){};
```

print in main method:

```
println("Maximum amount of money"+findMax(listOfAccounts));
```

Any help to clear the confusion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you want to find the number of items in a list, you can use `myList.size()`. Other than that, I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, countAccounts method was a silly example to give! I was going to say Perhaps findMaximum(ArrayList<Integer> max). how to use findMaximum(listOfAccounts)? as listOfAccounts is object, not an specific type arrayList. @khelwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to count the number of accounts you can do

```
int size = listOfAccounts.size();
```

if you want to extract a list of numbers from those accounts you can do

```
List<Integer> numberOfAccounts = listOfAccounts.stream()
                                            .map(a -> a.getNum())
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> how many ways I can use the object ArrayList to make the list useful?

Too many to count.

> Can I use listOfAccounts as Integer?

Its a List of Accounts.  If you want to use it as a list of Integers, you have to create a new List which contains the Integers you want.

> how to covert listOfAccounts as Integer ArrayList so that I can use them as in the method below?

You can't convert the list, but you can get an integer out.  I suggest you read the Javadoc for this class for more details.

```
int i = numberOfAccounts.get(i);
```

or

```
for(int i : numberOfAccounts) {
  // iterate over the list
```

or use t as a Stream

```
numberOfAccounts.stream()
              .forEach(System.out::println);
```

> how to use findMaximum(listOfAccounts)? as listOfAccounts is object, not an specific type arrayList.

If you just want the maximum for some field of an Account, you don't need to extract a `List<Integer>` first.

```
List<Account> accounts = ...
OptionalInt max = accounts.stream()
        .mapToInt(Account::getNum)
        .max();
```

Comment: The problem is: Both (int and iteration) giving me the error " Account cannot be converted to int". :(

Comment: @M.Harun Correct which is why I stated you need to convert your list of account to a list of Integers and gave you an example of how to do that. Let me make that clearer in my answer....

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter Lawrey